# Example to configure Seq for automatically send emails

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, seq

How can I configure Seq to automatically send emails when I receive a specific log?
For example using: Seq.App.EmailPlus.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Signal to define the filter criteria for the logs that you want to receive via email.

[image]

Install Seq.App.EmailPlus from NuGet (through Seq's UI), and add a new instance:

[image]

Configure the From/To email, SMTP host, etc. and select the Signal that you created in the first step.

[image]

This instance will send emails for every log that matches the filter defined in the Signal.